ACCP $\implies$ FD uses Axiom of Choice?
It is well-known that ACCP (every ascending chain of principal ideals terminates) implies FD (every non-zero non-unit element has a factorization into irreducibles), and the proof usually goes by contradiction. Suppose for contradiction that $r$ has no factorization. Then $r$ must itself be reducible, furnishing non-unit $r_1,r_1'$ such that $r = r_1 r_1'$. But $r_1, r_1'$ cannot both have factorization, and assuming that the former does not, without loss of generality, we have $(r) \subset (r_1)$. This argument, of course, applies for $r_1$ as well, so repeating the process infinitely yields a non-terminating ascending chain of principal ideals.
The repeating part does not seem very rigorous to me, however. Is there some form of axiom of choice involved? If so, is it countable choice or dependent choice?

I don't have a full answer for this, but as a trivial observation, the following are equivalent for a ring $R$ satisfying ACCP: (a) there is function $i: R \to R \cup { \bot }$ such that $i(r)$ is an irreducible such that $i(r) \mid r$, $r \nmid i(r)$; (b) there is a function $f: R \to R^*$ such that $f(r)$ is an irreducible factorisation of $r$. (Proof: $\Rightarrow$ follows by an obvious recursive algorithm; ACCP implies termination; $\Leftarrow$: just return the first element of the factorisation, if any).

You can, of couse, define $s$ via the full axiom of choice; you could also formulate the algorithm as a proof, which would give a version of the result via dependent choice. I'm not sure if the latter can be eliminated.

I assume we work with an integral domain $R$?

We can formalize the proof with the axiom of choice as follows.
Let $R$ be an integral domain satisfying the ascending chain condition for principal ideals. With the axiom of choice, there is a function $d$ that chooses for every non-zero non-unit reducible element $r$ a non-trivial divisor $d(r)$ of $r$ (meaning $d(r)$ is not a unit and not associated to $r$). With the axiom of choice, we also have a function $c$ that chooses for every non-empty subset of $R$ one of its elements (actually, we will only need it for subsets with at most $2$ elements). Notice that $c$ is the much more powerful function here, and we may also define $d$ using $c$ via $d(r) := c(\{\text{non-trivial divisors of } r\})$.
Assume that $r \in R$ is a non-zero non-unit element that it is not a product of irreducible elements (for short: indecomposable). Define a sequence of indecomposable elements $(r_n)$ with $r_{i+1} \mid r_i$ and $r_{i+1} \not\equiv r_i$ recursively as follows. We let $r_0 := r$. If $r_n$ is already defined, it is reducible (since irreducible elements are decomposable). We may factor it as
$$r_n = d(r_n) \cdot \frac{r_n}{d(r_n)}.$$
One of these factors must be indecomposable (otherwise, $r_n$ would be decomposable). It follows that the set
$$T := \left\{t \in \bigl\{d(r_n), \frac{r_n}{d(r_n)}\bigr\} : t \text{ is indecomposable}\right\}$$
is non-empty. Now define $r_{n+1} := c(T)$.
It follows that $(r_0) \subseteq (r_1) \subseteq \cdots$ is an ascending chain of principal ideals that does not terminate, contradiction.

Thanks for the elaborate answer! Your answer inspired me, however: can we argue that $r_{i + 1} \vert r_i \land r_{i + 1} \not \equiv r_i$ defines a total relation on R, precisely because it may be factored, and then apply dependent choice to obtain a sequence?

Which relation do you mean? (Your definition requires the sequence already.)

You're right; that's definitely not the right way to define it. What about on the set of indecomposables, for all $r$, there exists $r'$ such that $r' \vert r \land r' \not \equiv r$? And by the contradiction hypothesis the set of indecomposables is non-empty.
